# msbuild: how to register different versions of the same dll?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-framework-version

I have the following dll registration within my ms build now using the code below although we work with different code bases which might need different versions of the dll registered, i.e. MyLib.dll that represents the development version and another MyLib.dll that's for a production equivalent.  Is it possible to register a DLL this way?  I.e. potentially multiple MyLib.dlls but with some unique key or something..(?) 
In the example code below it seems to correctly remove any existing dll called MyLib and then to register the newest version.

Thanks,
James

```
<Target Name="MyLib">
<Exec Command="%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe ..\..\Library\MyLib.dll /unregister"></Exec>        
<Exec Command="%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe ..\..\Library\MyLib.dll"></Exec>
</Target>
```